# Реальное училище

Tags: этимология

Раньше было такое понятие как "реальное училище". А почему — реальное? Что, были и не реальные?)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для гимназий я нашел смысл в разделении:

> **классические** гимназии (изучали один или несколько древних языков) и **реальные** гимназии (без изучения древних языков).

А реальное училище, похоже, является дословным переводом немецкого Realschule, т. е. учебное заведение технической направленности (древние языки также, видимо, в них не преподавались).

Answer (score 2):

Да, эти слова являются терминами, которые означали различие от других школ, которые, в свою очередь, назывались классическими. 
То есть нереальными были классические училища.

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь, что дело не столько в пртивопоставлении реального училища и классической гимназии (оно больше плод последующей советской идеологии), сколько - **реального и духовного** образования, заведения обоих назывались училищами. Вообще в Российской империи насчитывалось как минимум пять основных типов заведений начального и среднего образования (в соверменных терминах). Если совсем честно, то я просто бросил поптыку систематизации на этой цифре.